# Subir una imagen a mysql con php sin necesidad de formulario

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas a todos como están..! bueno mi pregunta es: se puede subir una imagen a MySQL sin necesidad de hacer un formulario?

Lo que quiero hacer es que me suba automáticamente a la base de datos las imágenes que están en una carpeta, pues la verdad ando haciendo una aplicación donde me captura la pantalla del equipo y quiero tomar las capturas y poder ver esas fotos en otro equipo, pero quiero que guarde las capture en mysql o buscar una forma que el otro equipo las pueda ver.

este es el poco de codigo que llevo pero solo guarda la ruta.

```
<?php
$i=0;
while ($i<5) {
    require ('config.php');
    $i++;
    $Nombre = "Reporte".$i;
    $guardado = "../img/".$Nombre.".jpeg";
    $img = imagegrabscreen();
    $destino_1 = imagejpeg($img,$guardado);    

            $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Fallo al conectar con la Base de Datos.";

                exit();

            }

            mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_bd) or die ("No se encontro la Base de Datos");

            mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
    $guardar= "INSERT INTO img (ID, Nombre, Lugar) VALUES (0, '$Nombre', '$guardado') ";

        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$guardar);

        mysqli_close($conexion);
    sleep(15);
}
?>
```

Comment: a ver, si solo guarda la ruta, supongo que la BBDD, deberias darle un nombre predefinido a cada imagen, lo que se guarda en la base de datos son los nombres de los archivos (más la ruta si no cambias el nombre), mas no los archivos, asi que deberias mirar que al hacer la captura, mirar donde se guarda, si quieres mirar las capturas, guardadas ademas de verlas, a la hjora de hacer dicha visualizacion, deberias guardarlas en un directorio o carpeta que sea accesible para todos aquellos que puedan y quieran ver las capturas, deberias plantearte bien como lo quieres hacer.
Un saludo.

Comment: pues la verdad solo quiero es guardar la foto automaticamente a la base de datos, sin necesidad de que tenga que selecionar la foto. quiero ver si puedo hacer un script donde se seleccione solo las foto y las suba a la base de datos . Gracias por responder

Comment: Te guarda correctamente la ruta de la imagen? Si es así, simplemente tienes que mover la imagen que te haya enviado el usuario.

Comment: @HayateGS enttonces deberias hacer un Script el cual actue asincronamente con un PHP para que renombre las imagenes y las mueva a la carpeta donde quieres ver las imagenes, eso si el nombre debe coincidir tanto en la base de datos, como el nombre del archivo.

Comment: @EugeniBejan gracias por responder, si me guarda la ruta bien y al momento de mostrar la foto tambien la muestra con la ruta, pero quiero saber como busco o guardo las fotos de otro equipo secundario para que las muestre en el principal.

Comment: @juank Gracias por tu respuesta. ando viendo como hacer eso pues la verdad no tengo conocimiento sobre como guardar las fotos en la base de datos siempre sale error al guardarlas, y ya eh visto en varios foros y videos en youtube pero no me sale. me podrias dar un ejemplo por favor y gracias

Comment: si claro que si @HayateGS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suponiendo que recibes $_POST en algun sitio deberias hacer esto

```
//esto es par aque no te lo guarde con la tura C:\fakepath\nombredelfichero

$_POST['tu_fichero'] = basename($_POST['tu_fichero']);

//no sé como tendras las cosas pero ese metodo es para guardar en base de datos.
guardar_datos($_POST, $conn);
```

para hacer una especie de paripé deberias tener en html esto, el resto del formulario lo debes enviar a un .PHP aparte el de tiipo texto es lo que se almacenará en la base de datos, y obviamente el tipo File, es el que se moverá a donde tu le digas.

```
<div class="file-field input-field col s11">
     <div class="input-append">
          <input id="photoCover1"  value="" name="fichero"class="form-control" type="text" onclick="$('input[id=fichero1]').click();">
     </div>
     <label for="fichero1">Fichero</label>
</div>
```

lo de abajo es lo que se envia asincronamente y se mueve a las carpetas

```
   <div class="hide">
        <form name="fichero1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#">
            <input id="fichero1" name="fichero" type="file">
        </form> 
    </div>
```

este seria el codigo javacript

```
$('input[id=fichero1]').change(function() {
    $('#photoCover1').val($(this).val());
    subir_fichero();
});


function subir_fichero(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '.file_upload.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData($('form')[1]),
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false, 

        success: function(response){
            //$("#new_prod_card").html(response);


        }
    });
}

</script>
```

una vez se envie asicronamente el archivo el .file_upload lo recoge y lo envia a esta funcion

```
if ($_FILES['fichero']['name']!="")
{

    subir_fichero($_FILES);

}
```

dicha funcion contiene esto

```
function subir_fichero($fichero){

    $PATH = PATH_MIS_IMAGENES;

    move_uploaded_file($fichero['fichero']['tmp_name'], $PATH.$fichero['fichero']['name']);
    //var_dump($PATH.$fichero['fichero']['name']);

}
```

no sé si te sirva de algo pero he estado trabajando con esto, espero que si, lo que debe quedar claro es que una cosa es almacenar algo en una base de datos y otra el interactuar con ficheros.

un saludo

Comment: gracias por la ayuda :D!!! me sirvio esto esta mejor explicado que otros lados :D!!!

Comment: me alegro :) ojala logres algo con esto jaja :) un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que enviarlos como ficheros binarios (en base64, por ejemplo). Hay librerías que te permiten codificaciones así de manera muy sencilla.

Una vez codificado/s el/los archivo/s, tendrías que guardarlos en un campo para objetos, como BLOB, dependiendo del motor de base de datos que estés utilizando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. La verdad ya intente eso pero no se bien como se hace me guarda 1B y la foto pesa 64k cuando voy a llamar la foto no me sale entonces no se como hacerlo. me podrias dar un ejemplo por favor.

Comment: PHP tiene una función para codificar en base64, bastante simple además, `base64_encode()`.
Teniendo el PATH del fichero, sólo tendrías que cargarlo y, al momento de hacer la llamada a MySQL, codificarlo en base64.